# A continuous and integrable function has its maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

As the title says, $f \in C(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $f \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

I think it's true, but struggling to prove it. I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Take a function that is zero everywhere except that it has, as you move to infinity, ever increasing bumps that get taller and taller, but narrower too, and they get narrower way faster than they get taller, in such a way that the area of the $n$-th bump is $1/2^n$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Yes, right... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For an explicit construction of the type of function suggested in the comment above take $n=1$ and  $f(x)=\sum_k I_{(k-\frac 1 {k^{3}},k+\frac 1 {k^{3}}) }(x) (k^{4}|x-k|-k)$. This function is continuous and integrable but $|f(k)|=k \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample that's easy to write down:

$$f(x) = x\left ( \dfrac{2+\sin x}{3} \right )^{x^5},$$

although it requires some work to verify.